# Vue JS behave differently in production mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have app build in Vue js when I run on local or on the server in development mode it runs correctly data variables are being correctly printed and auth is working well but when I run in production mode by creating build then variable are not being printed and auth is not working well.

what could be the reason?.

is there any standard I should have to follow to have the consistent app in development and production?

Comment: Are your production and development environments otherwise identical?

Comment: @pcgben sorry I did not understand your comment. could you please add some explanation. thanks

Comment: @ShahzadFarukh he is asking if the OS & other things are identical on both of your environments?

Comment: on my local OS is the mac. on the server I have centos

Comment: Are you setting process.ENV variables?

Comment: I am making build through vue-cli and during the build, I am giving production EVN variable

Comment: @ShahzadFarukh Is the behaviour consistent in both of your environments?  That is: when you run in production mode are you experiencing the same behaviour in both MacOS and CentOS?   Can you please edit your question with details about your entire stack?